# How do I force an instance of a typeclass to be used in lean4?

Tags: functional-programming, lean

I was trying to learn lean and I accidentaly left the concatenate_junk type input as ˋStringˋ instead of ˋaˋ.

```
class ConcatenateJunk (a: Type u) where
  concatenate_junk: String -> String

instance: ConcatenateJunk String where
  concatenate_junk := λ x => x

instance: ConcatenateJunk Nat where
  concatenate_junk := λ x => "junk" ++ toString x

#eval ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk 42
```

THis led me think: how can I call `ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk` for the Nat instantiation? Since there's no type argument in the ˋconcatenate_junkˋ, the compiler does not know which instance to pick.

How do I select?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
class ConcatenateJunk (a: Type u) where
  concatenate_junk: a -> String  -- this line has changed

instance: ConcatenateJunk String where
  concatenate_junk := λ x => x

instance: ConcatenateJunk Nat where
  concatenate_junk := λ x => "junk" ++ toString x

#eval ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk 42
```

Your first `String` should have been an `a`.

Comment: yes but after I realized my mistake I got curious on how I could call concatenate_junk in the case where it has no type parameter, that is, it's ˋString -> Stringˋ

Comment: Well if it has type `String -> String` then you can't pass `42` because that's not a string.

Comment: how can I do it with a String?

Answer (score 0):

Lean detects that `a` is not constrained by the type of `concatenate_junk` and, rather than making it be an implicit argument like usual, it makes it be explicit. You can see this here:

```
class ConcatenateJunk (a: Type u) where
  concatenate_junk: String -> String

#check ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk
/-
ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk.{u} (a : Type u) [self : ConcatenateJunk a] (a✝ : String) : String
-/
```

And so, in this case to select one or the other, you can just pass `a` as the first argument.

```
#eval ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk String "hi"
-- "hi"

#eval ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk Nat "hi"
-- "junkhi"
```

In general, you can use keyword arguments:

```
#eval ConcatenateJunk.concatenate_junk (a := String) "hi"
-- "hi"
```